# Multiple Adapters in single RecyclerView

Tags: android

I tried to build a RecyclerView using 2 Adapters. Then I figured out that its not possible so I tried to combine 2 adapters into one but I got stuck somehow when I had to reference mine objects.
All I need is to display 4 different (code was made for 2 only) layouts files in a single recyclerView.
Thanks for any help.

````
**some imports

public class MultiAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    public static class ChestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView second_segment;

        public ChestViewHolder( View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            second_segment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.segment_tuesday);

        }
        **public void bind(MultiAdapter firstObj) {
             //object *
        }**
    }
    public static class BicepsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView first_segment;

        public BicepsViewHolder( View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            first_segment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.segment_monday);

        }
        public void bind(MultiAdapter secondObj) {
            //object *
        }
}
    }
    private static int ITEM_TYPE_C_T;
    private static int ITEM_TYPE_S_B;


    private List<Object> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public MultiAdapter(List<Object> items){
        this.items.addAll(items);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (items.get(position) instanceof MultiAdapter) {
            return ITEM_TYPE_C_T;
        }
        else{
            return ITEM_TYPE_S_B;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0; //*
    }

    @Override
    public ChestViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_S_B){
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.segment_one,parent,false);

            return new BicepsViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.segment_two,parent,false);
            return new ChestViewHolder(view); /**** Incompatible types
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder Holder, int position) {
        Object item = items.get(position);

        if (Holder instanceof ChestViewHolder) {
            ((ChestViewHolder) Holder).bind((FirstObj) item); //* bind
        } else {
            ((BicepsViewHolder) Holder).bind((SecondObj) item); //* bind
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: The main problem is with bind method.. Everytime I try to put something in, it doesnt work. Should I create toString method in the Exercise file or what should I do to prevent this error?    @Sujan Poudel                                                                                            
`public void bind(MultiAdapter firstObj) {
             Exercise exercise = new Exercise();
             firstObj = exercise; }`

Answer (score 0):

Just return the list size on getItemCount()

```java
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
      return items.size(); 
 }
```

also don't forget to set layout manager for the recyclerview